# Word-wrap grid cells in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid, word-wrap

*(This is not a question per se, I'm documenting a solution I found using Ext JS 3.1.0. But, feel free to answer if you know of a better solution!)*

The Column config for an Ext JS Grid object does not have a native way to allow word-wrapped text, but there is a `css` property to override the inline CSS of the `TD` elements created by the grid.

Unfortunately, the `TD` elements contain a `DIV` element wrapping the content, and that `DIV` is set to `white-space:nowrap` by Ext JS's stylesheet, so overriding the `TD` CSS does no good.

I added the following to my main CSS file, a simple fix that *appears* to not break any grid functionality, but allows any `white-space` setting I apply to the TD to pass through to the `DIV`.

```
.x-grid3-cell {
    /* TD is defaulted to word-wrap. Turn it off so
       it can be turned on for specific columns. */
    white-space:nowrap;
    }

.x-grid3-cell-inner {
    /* Inherit DIV's white-space from TD parent, since
       DIV's inline style is not accessible in the column
       definition. */
    white-space:inherit;
    }
```

YMMV, but it works for me, wanted to get it out there as a solution since I couldn't find a working solution by searching the Interwebs.

Comment: Overriding the CSS for things like this is the proper approach. Ext cannot possibly provide JS configs for every possible style that might be required. Any CSS that's non-structural can generally be overridden without a problem (that's the entire basis of creating custom themes).

Comment: if you're hiding at the same time (using 4.1), you may want to keep this issue in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12375769/640030

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not a "better solution", but a similar one. I recently needed to allow ALL cells in every grid to wrap. I used a similar CSS-based fix (this was for Ext JS 2.2.1):

```
.x-grid3-cell-inner, .x-grid3-hd-inner {
  white-space: normal; /* changed from nowrap */
}
```

I didn't bother with setting a style on the td, I just went right for the cell class.

Comment: On extjs 4: ".x-grid-cell-inner {
        white-space: normal;
    }"

Comment: How about Number Columns? This works fine for Ordinary Text Columns but it doesn't for number columns.

Answer (score 76):

If you only want to apply the wrapping to one column, you can add a custom renderer.

Here is the function to add:

```
function columnWrap(val){
    return '<div style="white-space:normal !important;">'+ val +'</div>';
}
```

Then add the `renderer: columnWrap` to each column you want to wrap

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
[...],
columns:[{   
     id: 'someID',
     header: "someHeader",
     dataIndex: 'someID',
     hidden: false,
     sortable: true,
     renderer: columnWrap           
}]
```

Comment: That's a great solution... but what if you need to edit the cell? TextField and TextArea seem to take up different amounts of the cell, but not the right amount.

Comment: This works good in Mozilla but not in IE8. Is there any solution for IE8?

Comment: Thanks,works perfect.Tester Over Extjs 4.2 in Chrome,Mozilla and Edge,works in all of them.

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to wrap text in certain columns and are using ExtJS 4, you can specify a CSS class for the cells in a column:

```
{
    text: 'My Column',
    dataIndex: 'data',
    tdCls: 'wrap'
}
```

And in your CSS file:

```
.wrap .x-grid-cell-inner {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: i think these css style tweaks as suggested in many other threads wont work because in-line css style would get priority over them

Comment: Adding !important will override inline styles if necessary.

Comment: Tried this but this doesn't work for IE8 Extjs4. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Other solution is that:

```
columns : [
    {
        header: 'Header',
        dataIndex : 'text',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, view) {
            metaData.style = "white-space: normal;";
            return value;
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Tried this but this doesn't work for IE8 `Extjs4`. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do is by setting the cellWrap to true as below.

cellWrap: true

Its working well in EXTJS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
cellWrap: true
```

If you still want to use css always try to work with ui's, variables, etc. within themes, or set the style with the style property.

Comment: Works only in ExtJs 5+