# extjs grid column text wrap around

Tags: extjs, datagrid

I'm trying to create a property grid with ExtJS. The problem I'm having is that the text is too wide for the column. Is there anyway to force text to wrap around and just create a taller row? Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/lordzardeck/pLYt3/1/

Basically i'd like the title row to expand to read this:

```
A Reason for Spelling (Level B):  
Teacher's Guidebook
```

is this possible? if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word-wrap grid cells in Ext JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106104/word-wrap-grid-cells-in-ext-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this CSS:

```
.x-property-grid .x-grid-row .x-grid-property-name .x-grid-cell-inner {
    white-space: normal;
}

.x-property-grid .x-grid-row .x-grid-property-name .x-grid-cell-inner,
.x-property-grid .x-grid-row-over .x-grid-property-name .x-grid-cell-inner {
    background-image: none;
}

.x-property-grid .x-grid-row .x-grid-property-name,
.x-property-grid .x-grid-row-over .x-grid-property-name
{
    background-position: -16px 1px;
    background-image: url("http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/resources/themes/images/default/grid/property-cell-bg.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: just added css to move the background image from a nested div (that doesn't stretch with the row) to the table cell itself

Comment: awesome! but just to let you know, you have to remove .x-grid-property-name from the first rule for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Use [customEditors](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-cfg-customEditors) property of the grid.

See your [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/o_nix/pLYt3/2/).

Comment: that's useful, but I need it to display the text (not textarea) like that even when not editing.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `white-space: normal;` causes rendering issues when scrolling, using ExtJS 6

You should set `cellWrap: true` on the column, as pointed out by this thread:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205554-extjs-grid-column-text-wrap-around-auto-expand