# ExtJS read only text area in property grid

Tags: extjs

I have a property grid within which is currently a `displayfield`. I have been asked to make this particular field a multi-line field, so that text is wrapped around and carriage returns in the text are shown correctly.

I looked at a `textareafield`, but this seems to ignore `readOnly: true`, `editable: false` and methods of avoiding edits such as `beforeedit: function(){return false;}`.

I also tried to try and apply multiple line inserts (converting them to `</br>`) as part of the renderer within the `displayfield` , but this does not seem to work either.

What is the most efficient method of achieving this? Am I missing something simple in the API that provides the functionality I require?

I'd like to think this can be abstracted to a general case quite easily, but can provide code if deemed necessary.

EDIT:

To try and clarify my problem, I need a field that:

1. Cannot be edited by the user; no text bar and typing in the field.
2. Allows for multiple lines of text to be shown, by both word-wrap and
   by carriage returns/new lines

Think of a textareafield (expands to show all its contents) crossed with a displayfield (no editing capability).

Comment: wouldn't labels or column templates solve your problem? http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/docs/Ext.grid.column.Template.1/viewer.html

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Are you asking how to display line breaks when it's not editing? Or how to prevent editing? Or to show a read only copy when the user edits?

Comment: I will try to clarify via an edit.

Comment: @lascort, your suggestions don't appear to fit propertygrids; could you point me towards a fiddle showing their implementation in propertygrids that demonstrates solving my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a `textareafield` with disabled set to true..
You can have new lines on the text with `\n`.

Hope that helps ! :)

Comment: The `textareafield` doesn't appear to word-wrap; what is the setting to ensure long lines of text don't disappear off the edge of the text area with '...'?

Comment: I don't seem to be having that problem.. what version of ext are you using? Check an example here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5s4

Comment: I've found a workaround in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106104/word-wrap-grid-cells-in-ext-js, which wraps the text